# Syntax Highlighting in TextMate2

Tags: syntax-highlighting, textmate-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get syntax highlighting working in TextMate 2](https://superuser.com/questions/463770/how-to-get-syntax-highlighting-working-in-textmate-2)

I pulled TextMate2 from GitHub and built it but I can't get the syntax highlighting to work.  I've installed the bundles using the  built-in bundle installer and I've installed themes (which also don't seem to be working). Is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: Did you enable the bundles via app settings?

Comment: I do.  It seems intermittent.  I closed the app and posted the question and when I started it again it worked.  Then I closed the app and started it again and it didn't!

Comment: It started working for me after I installed the "Themes for syntax highlight..." theme and restarted TextMate.

Comment: Thank you Sjors!  That worked.  If you put it as an answer, I'll accept it.