# How to get syntax highlighting working in TextMate 2

Tags: themes, syntax-highlighting, textmate-2

I just cloned TextMate 2 from GitHub.  Followed the instructions in the readme file and everything went smooth with the installation.  However, there is no syntax highlighting.

No problem – just need themes, right?  I found a theme I liked, downloaded and installed.  Everything seemed to go fine.  However, quitting and restarting TextMate 2 doesn't give me my theme in the menu I see.

*View > Theme > No Themes Loaded*

What?

Answer (score 16):

*View > Theme* is a red-herring.  Ignore it.

Go to *TextMate > Preferences* and choose *Bundles*.  Themes are in bundles in TextMate 2.  In the Bundles tab, you can click themes near the top to filter theme-bundles.

Choose the bundle called *Themes*.  When you check the box, it will download and install. Quit, relaunch and you're done.